# SOSL Trailhead Challenge Issue

Tags: sosl

I'm new to salesforce but learing a bunch.
I'm working on the SOSL challenge. My code is returning the correct data (I think) but I still fail the challenge. Any guidance would be super appreciated.

```
public class ContactAndLeadSearch {
    public static List<List<SObject>> searchContactsAndLeads (String query)
    {
        List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND:query IN NAMES FIELDS RETURNING Contact(FirstName,LastName),Lead(FirstName,LastName)];
        return searchList;
    }
}
```

When I run in the Query Editor,

```
FIND {smith} IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING Contact(FirstName,LastName),Lead(FirstName,LastName)
```

All the correct contacts and leads show.
I've tried various combinations (Name),(LastName) and just with nothing after (ie. Contact).
Heeeelp Please. And Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! We don't generally answer trailhead challenge questions, because the purpose is to learn and figure out these on your own. That said, we're not above giving simple hints. In this case, my hint to you is that programming is every precise. You must spell everything correctly. Just a single typo is sufficient to cause a compiler error, which means your code won't deploy or run. Carefully read your code once, twice, three times if you need to. Being a programmer is to be detail-oriented.

Comment: And that is why I'm not longer going to use salesforce.

Comment: Being a programmer is a detail-oriented profession. It doesn't matter if it's Salesforce or something else. If you can't spot the difference, you're going to find it's going to be rough no matter which programming career you choose. Salesforce careers pay better than most in technology. I wish you the best of luck no matter which way you decide to go.

Comment: Yup and in my culture knowledge should always be given away freely. The fact that they won't help train you or hire you shows that it is not a honorable institution. Quit frankly its a scam. yes it pays well after you've spent months learning their horribly worded and setup system. It is not designed for intuitive productivity, but to force you to spend money to learn it and money to take the tests... scam??? I think so. But if you have thousands of dollars and time to waste learning its cumbersome system then yes, it is a good option.

Comment: Salesforce is no more a scam than NetSuite, Oracle, Microsoft, etc. They all charge for certification and training. Trailhead is over 300 modules of *free* information. And you can learn in a real *free* org. They just ask that you log in every once in a while. This network isn't even an officially sanctioned Salesforce platform, it's hosted by [so]. And they have much harsher standards for questions and answers than we do. All I was saying is that maybe `name` versus `names` might be part of your problem. Just a small attention to detail.